# stsadm deploy fails

Tags: stsadm

I am trying to deploy a SharePoint 2010 feature using the following commands:

> stsadm -o addsolution -filename %featureWSPFile% 
>   stsadm -o
>   deploysolution -name %featureWSPFile% -url http://localhost:2010
>   -immediate -allowGacDeployment
>  stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
>   stsadm -o
>   activatefeature -name %featureName% -url http://localhost:2010

However, I get the following error message:

> Failed to find the XML file at location '14\Template\Features\%featureName%\feature.xml'

Comment: Most likely a mismatch between what you're referring to as the featurename when you execute the script and what's in the feature def.  Can you post your solution manifest and feature.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs does not always wait until the job you created has finished processing, nor does it ensure that the job processed successfully.  A safer approach is to watch the solution deployment status in Central Administration and not execute your ActivateFeature command until you see that it has deployed.

I have also seen it happen where the "Windows SharePoint Services Administration" and/or "Windows SharePoint Services Timer" service has stopped on one or more of the servers in the farm.  When this happens your Activate command will fail because it was not able to deploy the feature to the server where that service was stopped.  You need to make sure those two services are running on all servers in your farm.

In either case, you will see what is going on by looking at:
Central Administration -> System Settings -> Farm Management -> Manage Farm Solutions

Comment: I am unable to find Operations in Sharepoint 2010 Central Admin. Also, based on what you are saying does that mean there is no reliable way to automatically deploy sharepoint features?

Comment: Sorry, I listed the path in SP 2007. I've updated the response with the path for SP2010

Comment: The steps you are using will automatically deploy features as long as the required services are running on all servers in the farm.  If those services are not running then there is *NO* way to deploy the solution across the farm.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Part of the problem was that the Timer service was set to run under an incorrect account and wasn't working. It still lists the wsp file as "deploying". Is there a way to "force deploy" it?

Comment: This still sounds like there is a service not started somewhere.  Did you check that the Admin service was running as well (this is listed a few lines above the timer service and is not Central Admin).

Comment: If you click on the solution name itself, it should list the servers that it has deployed to and from that you should be able to spot which one is missing.  check that server for an issue with the timer or Admin services.  Once all services are running it should correct itself.  However, if it does not, you should be able to forcefully retract it via the UI and then delete it and run your install script again.